# How to override a CLI command?

Tags: magento2, module, overrides, cli

I'd like to know if I can override a CLI, specifically the `bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

I want to override the class **Magento\Setup\Validator\DbValidator**, the method **checkDatabasePrivileges**.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to go about this, one is to replace the **Magento\Setup\Validator\DbValidator** system wide with your customized version. The other is to only change it for the `bin/magento setup:upgrade` command.

I assume you prefer the send one. To archieve this, first create a class in your custom module which extends **Magento\Setup\Validator\DbValidator** and override the **checkDatabasePrivileges** method to change the implementation to suit your needs. Then you need to tell Magento to use this class instead of the default **Magento\Setup\Validator\DbValidator**.
For this create a **etc/di.xml** file in your custom module with the following contents :

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Setup\Model\Installer">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="dbValidator" xsi:type="object">Custom\Module\Path\To\Class</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Replace **Custom\Module\Path\To\Class** with the custom class you created and run. `bin/magento setup:di:compile`

Your class should now be used instead of the default one.

The setup:upgrade command uses the **Magento\Setup\Model\Installer** class which uses the **Magento\Setup\Validator\DbValidator**. We are telling Magento that everytime the **Magento\Setup\Model\Installer** class is used in the system, we want it to use our custom class instead of the original **Magento\Setup\Validator\DbValidator**.

Comment: It didn't work because is overriding the class in vendor folder, so doesn't affect my setup:upgrade that uses the same class in /setup/src/Magento/Setup/Validator/DBValidator.php, I'd like to know how to override the /setup/src/... class.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the file is located, the override that we did in the di.xml works based on the class name. There must be another thing wrong then. If you want you can try `<preference for="Magento\Setup\Validator\DbValidator" type="Custom\Module\Path\To\Class" />` to replace the class system wide. Also confirm that the module were you are adding the di.xml is enabled and working, the di.xml is located directly under etc as opposed to etc/frontend.

Comment: How do you do it where DbValidator is overridden with composer?